# How to make a counter for rock, paper, scissors game?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a rock, paper, scissors game for class, but I'm stuck with creating a counter. I declared global variables and thought it would be simple to just add +1 every time somebody wins, but it doesn't seem to be working. Here's my code of what I'm using now. What should I add to make the counter work?

```
var game = false;
var playerScore = 0;
var compScore = 0;

while (game != true){
    var userChoice = prompt("Pick your poison: Rock, paper, or scissors. Type 'exit' to quit.").toLowerCase();

    if (userChoice === "rock" || userChoice === "paper" || userChoice === "scissors"){
        var computerChoice = randomizeComputer();
        console.log("You chose: " + userChoice);
        console.log("Computer chose: " + computerChoice);
        compare(userChoice);

    } else if (userChoice === "exit"){
        console.log("Thanks for playing");
        game = true;
    } else {
        console.log("Sorry, you typed something we couldn't recognize");
    }
}


function compare (choice){

    //If it's the same thing
    if (choice === computerChoice){
        return console.log("It's a tie");
    } 

    //If user chooses rock
    if (choice === "rock"){

        if (computerChoice === "scissors"){
            return console.log("You win!");
            counter(1);

        } else if (computerChoice === "paper"){
            return console.log("You lose!");
        }
    }

    //If user chooses paper
    if (choice === "paper"){

        if (computerChoice === "rock"){
            return console.log("You win!");
        } else if (computerChoice === "scissors"){
            return console.log("You lose!");
        }
    }

    //If user chooses scissors
    if (choice === "scissors"){

        if (computerChoice === "paper"){
            return console.log("You win!");
        } else if (computerChoice === "rock"){
            return console.log("You lose!");
        }
    }
}

//Randomizes 
function randomizeComputer () {

    var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
    if (i === 1){
        return "rock";
    } else if (i === 2){
        return"paper";
    } else {
        return "scissors";
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly, does _"doesn't seem to be working"_ mean?

Comment: Debug and narrow down your problems. Then tackle them one by one.

Comment: What have you already tried regarding your counter?

Comment: 1.computerChoice  isn't define in compare function 2. counter isn't define